# Procedimiento entrada datos (clave duplicada)

Tags: stored-procedure, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Estoy haciendo unos ejercicios con procedimientos almacenados. Tengo que introducir una incidencia con su número, equipo, hora, trabajador... Y que el procedimiento chequee si el número de incidencia ya existía previamente. En cuyo caso me diga X y sino Y e inserte los datos.

Tras estar trasteando un rato estoy atascado, ahora mismo me dice que no pinta ahí ni el begin ni el where (me lo creo jajaja)

Os inserto el código a ver si me podéis echar un cable. Gracias de antebrazo!

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE entrar_incidencia(
    p_IdIncidencia NUMBER:= '&IdIncidencia',
    p_Equipo NUMBER:= '&Equipo',
    p_Descripción VARCHAR:= '&Descripción',
    p_Fechahora TIMESTAMP:= 'Fechahora',
    p_Trabajador NUMBER:= '&Trabajador'
    )
IS
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT (IdIncidencia) INTO p_IdIncidencia FROM Incidencias
    WHERE IdIncidencia=p_IdIncidencia
    IF p_IdIncidencia=0 THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('El número de incidencia ya existe');
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO Incidencias (IdIncidencia, Equipo, Descripción, Fechahora, Trabajador)
        VALUES (p_IdIncidencia, p_Equipo, p_Descripción, p_Fechahora,p_Trabajador);
        dbms_output.put_line('La incidencia se ha registrado correctamente');
    END IF;
END;
/
```

Errores:
10/5      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored -- Línea SELECT
12/5      PL/SQL: ORA-00933: comando SQL no terminado correctamente -- Línea IF
14/5      PLS-00103: Se ha encontrado el símbolo "ELSE" cuando se esperaba uno de los siguientes:     ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod    null pragma raise return select update while with          << continue close current delete fetch lock    insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall    merge pipe purge json_exists json_value json_query    json_object json_array
19/1      PLS-00103: Se ha encontrado el símbolo "END"
Errores: comprobar log de compilador

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! pone el procedimiento completo.. y ese where, en que query esta? SELECT COUNT (IdIncidencia) INTO p_IdIncidencia <- esto que es? hay un and ahi abajo, que no se que hace... mezclaste partes del query con partes del SP?

Comment: He añadido el "from" que viene antes del where para indicar la tabla, que me faltaba. El select count lo que quiero es que coja los valores introducidos en la columna IdIncidencia y me los compare con el p_IdIncidencia que es el valor que introduzco yo con el teclado.

El AND es que no sé como añadir que además de introducir los valores una vez comprobado que no es una clave duplicada, que me aparezca el mensaje de "La Incidencia se ha registrado correctamente".

Comment: bueno.. yo que vos, reviso toda la documentacion de SP.. pues muchas cosas, no se escriben asi... el AND es totalmente innecesario.. las instrucciones se ejecutan una atras de la otra.. count cuenta.. y como va a hacer para comparar un monton de valores (que no sabemos de donde salen) con otro? tal vez querias guardar los valores en un cursor, e ir verificandolos uno a uno??? yo te recomiendo (ya que estas aprendiendo) que vayas solucionando los problemas de a uno.. tu primer problema es ver como obtener los valores de la tabla y compararlos con el que viene (sigue....)

Comment: que ya te digo, no necesitas.. porque para eso tenes un where y un query que devuelva una cantidad de registros.. no? salvo que eso sea tu query incompleto.. usa el boton [edit] y arregla tu pregunta...

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas. El tema es que donde estoy estudiando los apuntes son muy incompletos, he estado googleando viendo vídeos y de todo ese remix he creado ese código. 
Es probable que me venga bien un cursor, pero intentaba a ver si podía hacerlo de la forma más sencilla. REalmente la única clave que quiero que me compare es la IdIncidencia, el resto pueden estar repetidas. 

Voy a editar el post como me indicas con el código actual y los errores que tengo.

Comment: sobra una coma antes de ) ;)

Comment: Efectivamente con esa "," antes del ")" damos un paso pero saltan más errores. Edito el post

Comment: falta un punto y coma.. no podemos ir uno a uno, haciendo de test.. que tal, si empezas de vuelta, y vas revisando linea por linea, a ver cuales son tus problemas?

Comment: Si eso hago. Chequear, buscar en google/youtube y lo que gano por un lado lo pierdo de otro. No sé como resolver esto actualmente sin tener 214 fallos cada vez que ejecuto el código

Comment: despues de cada instruccion.. va un punto y coma... estas tratando de resolver el problema, en lugar de entender como funciona un pl...